# How can I solve this exercise? (Variance with indicator function)

Tags: self-study, variance, inference, multinomial-distribution, indicator-function

I am trying to compute the variance of T but I am having some troubles. T is defined like $T=\sum_{i=1}^m Y_i$ and $Y_i=YI(U_i \leq \varrho) + Y_i^oI(U_i >\varrho)$ where I(.) is an indicator function and $Y, Y_i^0, Y_i^1,...,Y_i^m$ are IID random variables distributed as a multinomial random variable $M_k(\pi,m)$, $U_1,..., U_m$ are IID r.vs distributed uniformly in the interval (0,1) and $\varrho$ is a real number in $0<\varrho<1$.

Can somebody help? I am struggling in getting the correct result which is equal to ${1+\varrho^2(m-1)}mV(\pi)$ where $V(\pi) = {diag(\pi)-\pi\pi'}$. While I get something like $\pi(1-\pi)+\pi^2 - m^2\pi\pi'$.

I computed it like:
$$
V(T)=E(T^2)+E(T)^2= E[\sum_i^m Y_i^2] - (m\pi)^2= E[\sum_i^m(YI(U_i \leq \varrho) + Y_i^oI(U_i >\varrho))^2] - (m\pi)^2= E[\sum_i^m(Y^2I(U_i \leq \varrho) + Y_i^{o2}I(U_i >\varrho) + 2*YY_i^oI(U_i \leq \varrho)I(U_i >\varrho)] - (m\pi)^2= \sum_i^m[E(Y^2)P(U_i \leq \varrho) + E(Y_i^{o2})P(U_i >\varrho) + 2*E(YY_i^o)P(U_i \leq \varrho)P(U_i >\varrho)] - (m\pi)^2 = \sum_i^m[(\pi(1-\pi)+\pi^2)P(U_i \leq \varrho) + (\pi(1-\pi)+\pi^2)P(U_i >\varrho)- (m\pi)^2= \sum_i^m[(\pi(1-\pi)+\pi^2)[P(U_i \leq \varrho) + P(U_i >\varrho)]- (m\pi)^2= \pi(1-\pi)+\pi^2 - (m\pi)^2
$$

Can somebody show me how to compute this? It is very important for me to understand it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the correct result, what did you find and how?

Comment: I edited the question adding the correct result and the result that I got. I have tried different ways to compute it. Both using the fact that $VAR(T) = E(T^2) - E(T)^2$  and also by just simply computing the variance. But it doesn't work and I also get two different results depending on how I compute it.. so I think that I am making some big error..

Comment: Can you also add your full derivation so that a person who is looking at your question doesn't need to do all the steps again, and maybe can directly pinpoint your error. Also, in the definition of $Y_i$, you always use $Y_i^0$, but you have other RVs in the form $Y_i^j$. Plus, what is $M_k(\pi, m)$?

Comment: It is a multinomial random variable. Now I have edited the question and there are all the passages.

Comment: Why are $Y_i^1, Y_i^2 ...$ not used in your expression, and are $Y, Y_i$ vectors? If so, you can't square them. If no, $\pi\pi'$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Actually I don't know I just have this as introduction. I know that $\pi$ Is a vector of probabilities of dimension k because we are considering a multivariate distribution of dimension k. But I think that $Y_i^0$ is not a vector... This is all I know and this is why I am asking for help....

Comment: Actually in the expression is used only $Y_i^0$ and not the others. It is the expression that states it

Comment: I think sharing your derivation made it a very good `self-study` question but It's hard to answer it with these unknowns. I still can't get what $Y_i^o$ is and how are $Y_i^1,Y_i^2...$ used. If $Y_i^o$ is not a vector, $Y_i$ is not as well. Then $T$ is not a vector either. But, in your calculation, you replaced $E[T^2]$ with $m^2\pi\pi^T$, which is a matrix. I can't see a consistent flow in your definitions & solution. Also, the answer is in matrix form, which means $T$ should be a vector and $Y_i$ as well.

Comment: Actually the correct solution states that $\pi$ is a vector and so $m^2\pi\pi'$ a matrix. About the Ys I can say that in the definition is used only the $Y_i^o$ and not the others and actually you are right so I have that they are vectors too.

Comment: And the solution that I need to find is specified to be a covariance matrix. Hope this might help you in helping me!